# SharePoint Designer 2010 keeps asking me to install it over and over

Tags: sharepoint-designer, installation

I am not SharePoint savvy (and especially not programming savvy). I am trying to design stuff in 2010 however, at my boss's request, and cannot. Every time I click "Edit in SharePoint Designer" it asks me to install it. I've installed it 3 times now. It just keeps coming back to the install it page. I hate computers. Any help is much appreciated.

More details: Running Windows 7, Office 2010, SharePoint/Designer 2010, installed the 32 bit version.

Answer (score 0):

Just install it from here [32 Bit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16573) or [64 bit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24309) (Depends on your OS version and other Office apps installed)

I also find those links in the browser never work.  After you install one of these, open SPD, type in your URL, and navigate to your page.

Comment: That didn't work. It downloaded the same as the link from the site, and then when I tried to open it, it took me to the download it page again.

Comment: Did you open just SPD..not the link through IE.  Are you using IE 64 bit? Use 32 bit.  Check your add-ons http://www.myfriedmind.com/2011/11/sharepoint-designer-2010-prompts-even-when-installed/